# Adicionar caractere no meio de uma string

Tags: javascript, string, concatenação-de-string

### Problema

Como adicionar caractere no meio de uma string javascript?

### Por exemplo:

```
var string = "aacc"; // eu quero colocar as letras bb no meio da aa e cc
```

Quero que a `string` tenha esse valor `aabbcc`

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Dividindo a string no meio**

```js
var string = "aacc";
var metade = Math.floor(string.length / 2);
var resultado = string.substr(0,metade)+"bb"+string.substr(metade);


// o código abaixo é só para teste:
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resultado;
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Resultados:

```
// "aacc"=> "aabbcc"
// "aaaccc"=> "aaabbccc"
// "batata"=> "batbbata"
```

**Alternativas para divisão em lugar fixo**

Pegando dois caracteres do primeiro (começa de 0) em diante, e dois do terceiro:

```
//Index:      0123
var string = "aacc";
var resultado = string.substr(0,2)+"bb"+string.substr(2,2);
```

Alternativamente, pegando dois da esquerda e dois da direita:

```
//Index      -4321 
var string = "aacc";
var resultado = string.substr(0,2)+"bb"+string.substr(-2);
```

Ou, pegando dois da esquerda e do terceiro em diante:

```
var string = "aacc";
var resultado = string.substr(0,2)+"bb"+string.substr(2);
```

Answer (score 8):

Variável "string" recebe o seu texto.
Variável "m" localiza o "meio" da sua string.
Variável "r" retorna a string adicionando "bb" ao meio do texto passado.

Para isso utilizei substr(0,m) que inicia a contagem dos caracteres em zero e vai até o meio ("m") que é concatenado com "bb" e concatenado ao que sobrou da string quebrada.

```
var string = "aacc"; 
var m = Math.floor(string.length / 2); 
var r= string.substr(0,m)+"bb"+string.substr(m);
```

Answer (score 6):

Criei uma função que concatena o valor determinado por você na metade da quantidade total de de caracteres do seu texto, ele retorna uma string com o valor já concatenado.

```
function Inserir(string, valor)
{
 var i = Math.floor(string.length / 2);
 return string.substr(0, i).concat(valor).concat(string.substr(i));
}
```

Uso: `Inserir("aacc", "bb");`

Answer (score 4):

**Solução**

```
var string = "aacc";
var final  =  string.substring(0,2) + "bb" + string.substring(2);
```

**Links:**
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 0):

Se quis dizer inserir uma string dentro da outra:

```
function inserirTexto(TEXTO_ORIGEM, TEXTO_INSERIDO, INDICE) {
    return(""
        + TEXTO_ORIGEM.substring(0, INDICE)
        + TEXTO_INSERIDO
        + TEXTO_ORIGEM.substring(INDICE)
    );
}
```

Uso: `var teste = inserirTexto("Isso é teste.", "um ", 7)`

Como resultado a variável teste será "Isso é um teste."